# compute order x/z in Q

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, function-fields

Let $x^3+y^2z+yz^2+\alpha^3z^3=0$ be a curve over $F_{16}$ where $\alpha$ is primitive element for $F_{16}$ and $\alpha^4+\alpha+1=0$. The point $Q=(0:1:0)$
is only infinity point this curve. I want to compute order $x/z$ in $Q$
(For more information is attached).

[image]`[a][2]`

Comment: This way may not be familiar to you, but I hope it makes sense: set $z=1$, giving $y^2+y=x^3+a^3$. You want the order of $x$ at the single point on the line at infinity. That order is $-2$: $x$ has the two zeroes $(0,\beta)$ and $(0,\beta+1)$, where $\beta^2+\beta=\alpha^3$, for $\beta\in F_{16^2}$. The only poles must be at $Q$.